# Error 404: while deleting Calendar Event

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am getting following Error while deleting Event......

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
```

`Not Found [404`]

Here is the code:

```
public static string delete(CalendarService service, string id)
{`enter code here`
    try
    {
        //id = ja7jihu9eepa2l7h15d1vusf19
        return service.Calendars.Delete(id).Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can Anybody suggest me?

Comment: I would try and do a calendars.get on that id it doesn't look valid.    valid calendar id looks more like this 11gpgricpq0mjpi567806321g@group.calendar.google.com

Comment: @DaImTo I have changed my code. Event ICalUID is ja7jihu9eepa2l7h15d1vusf19@google.com. But it still throws same error.

Comment: @DaImTo It's done. I have deleted by EventsResource.DeleteRequest and Passed "Primary", "ja7jihu9eepa2l7h15d1vusf19"(Event Id) and Execute the request.

Comment: Its a little confusing on what you are trying to do.  Your question says you are trying to delete a calendar event but your code is trying to delete a calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete an event, you need to call Events.Delete() providing both, calendar ID and event ID. A calendar ID is an email address of the calendar while the event ID is an alphanumeric event identifier (like the one you have commented out).

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete